# How does the compiler figure out that we are declaring an int or char without the datatype in python?

Tags: python, types

When we initialize any value in python, we don't have to declare the datatype along with it as in the case of programming languages like C/C++. Then how does the compiler figure out what datatype it is?

Let's say I am initializing:
`c = 2`
and
`c = 'a'`

How does the compiler know the difference between both of this?

I have already tried searching for the results but failed to get a proper one.

Comment: So first, there's no compiler, it's an interpreter. It's also not assigning a static type at all. If you play around a bit, you can easily make python code that will generate runtime bugs that would be caught as compile-time bugs in C or Java.

Comment: There are languages that use "type inference" to assign a static type without requiring an explicit type parameter from the programmer, by the way. That's not what Python is doing, but if you're curious, look up Type Inference

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, In **Static Typed language(here type refers to data type), type of variables is checked at compile time while in Dynamic Typed language type checking is done at run-time**. Hence Static Typed language like Java, C, C++ we need to declare the variables and its data type before assigning the value to it. Python is a Dynamic Typed language and hence, type checking is done at run-time.

Since **python is dynamic typed language**, python interpreter automatically binds the type to its variable hence, we don’t need to define variables types before using it.

`a = 15`

Here, we are simply creating a variable ‘a’ with value 15. Interpreter will do following steps:

Interpreter will first check that 15 is numeric literal and it does not have decimal point either, hence it will create object of class ‘int’ using Metaclasses. Metaclasses are class of class which defines how class will behave. It may be little confusing, in simple terms, Metaclasses is just stuffs which creates object of class.

**Conclusion:-**
Python is Dynamic typed language and hence it automatically binds type to its variable. Python creates object of inbuilt type with the help of Metaclasses. Variables contains the references to objects.